# What view function can I call to determine if a user owns an nft minted on paras

Tags: nearprotocol

I know from the zero to hero nft tutorial if I know the contract account id that minted it I should be able to call:

near view example-nft.testnet nft_tokens_for_owner '{"account_id": "'$NEARID'"}'

But what is the account id for a nft that was minted using paras? Do I need to search through a list of all paras tokens or is there a way to simply check for a single collection?

I'm thinking about making a fan game for an nft I like only accessible to users with that nft.

Currently reading these docs, but if anyone wants to answer might speed things up for me.
https://docs.paras.id/getting-started

Comment: Can you give more details about your question? if i understand what it says, you are asking for the nft id? or if you mean what you need to put as an argument inside the json, it should be the id of the owner of the nft.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see which NFTs a user owns on Paras, you can call the view-function from the near-cli like this:

```
export NEAR_ENV=mainnet # make sure you switch from testnet to mainnet
near view x.paras.near nft_tokens_for_owner '{"account_id": "'$NEARID'"}'
```

Paras.id also has a method called `nft_tokens_by_series` ([found it on their GitHub repo](https://github.com/ParasHQ/paras-nft-contract/blob/4088a1b75403f7742b975f4d747a84ea9d88e2e6/paras-nft-contract/src/lib.rs#L776)), which takes one (string) argument, `token_series_id`. You can use the near-cli to get all NFTs for your series, and then see if the user owns one of your tokens.

```
near view x.paras.near nft_tokens_by_series '{"token_series_id": "id"}' # try id 49585 to get my own Mirror Crystals series
```

You can find the `token_series_id` in the URL when you inspect the details of an NFT on Paras.id (e.g. my own series https://paras.id/token/x.paras.near::49585/49585:2).

You can also do something similar with the [near-api-js](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/javascript-library) if you need to call the API from a browser or a Node.js application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of understand completely your question, but you can list all the stores of any account with a simple "http get" call:

```
https://helper.mainnet.near.org/account/jeph.near/likelynfts
```

*Just change my account below for the user account.

And then knowing that the user has (or not) paras NFT you can make the next "http post":

To: `https://rpc.mainnet.near.org/`
Body:

```
{
    "method": "query",
    "params": {
        "request_type": "call_function",
        "account_id": "x.paras.near",
        "method_name": "nft_tokens_for_owner",
        "args_base64": "eyJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiamVwaC5uZWFyIn0=",
        "finality": "optimistic"
    },
    "id": 158,
    "jsonrpc": "2.0"
}
```

*Below "args_base64" are: `{"account_id":"jeph.near"}` , again, change my account and encode to base64.

It will return the info from all the NFTs that the user has from Paras.
The first get is not 100% necessary, but better be sure the user has or not NFTs from Paras, and then make the post.